# Convert tree of dictionaries to multidimensional list

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary like this (Python):

```
{'G': 
     {'G': 
          {'T': 
               {'A': 'end'},
          'C': 'end'},
     }, 
 'C': {'G': 'end'}
}
```

How can I convert it to a multidimensional array like this one?:

```
['G', 
      ['G', 
          ['T', ['A'],
           'C']
       ], 
  'C', ['G'] 
]
```

Thank you

Comment: If 'C' is in the same level as G in the dict, why isn't it in the same level in the list?

Comment: I edited it and hope it makes sense now

Comment: What happened to all the `'$'`?

Comment: Your desired output isn't a valid Python list; the braces don't match.  Is this because you forgot a `]` at the end, or because you have an extra `[` at the start?

Comment: Good point. I read it as an extra `[`, but that inconsistency is significant.

Comment: Yes guys you're right.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {
 'G': 
     {'G': 
          {'T': 
               {'A': {'$': '$'}},
          'C': {'$': '$'}}
     }, 
 'C': {'G': {'$': '$'}}
}

def merge(dct):
    return [[k] + merge(v) for k,v in dct.items() if isinstance(v, dict)]

>>> merge(d)
[['C', ['G']], ['G', ['G', ['C'], ['T', ['A']]]]]
```

one more variant:

```
def merge(dct):
    l = []
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            l.append(k)
            m = merge(v)
            if m:
                l.append(m)
    return l


>>> merge(d)
['C', ['G'], 'G', ['G', ['C', 'T', ['A']]]]
```

Comment: Close, and maybe close enough, but there are two discrepancies: 1) we're assuming that order doesn't matter; 2) the structure is a little off, as neighboring keys are written above to be part of the same list; i.e. with your order, Federico's desired answer would be `['C', ['G'], ['G', ['G', ['C', 'T', ['A']]]]]`.

Comment: What happened to the sub dict `{'$': '$'}` under `'A'` and `'C'`?  I think your comprehension need to be: `def tree(dct): return [[k] + tree(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else [k] for k,v in dct.items()]`

Comment: Oops, my structure isn't quite right because of the inconsistency noted above. I think the second variant makes more sense.

Comment: @dawg look in question, author want result list without $, but i agree with you

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm assuming that you don't care about the order of keys in your dictionary, since dictionaries are unordered. If you do care, then there's no solution that will do quite what you want unless you switch to using `collections.OrderedDict` or equivalent.

Second, though you are now using the string `'end'` as your sentinel value to indicate where processing should stop, there's no indication that we should do any further processing on *any* value that's not a dictionary. The code can be modified to accommodate other kinds of recursion, but for now we'll keep it this simple, and just skip all non-dictionary values in the tree (though we *will* process their keys).

With those assumptions, I would do this with a recursive pair of functions. In this one, the `transform` is written so that you can use this kind of pattern with other transformation functions if you want. The operation of `transform` is a bit more complicated than a list comprehension because we are splicing the list of results into the output list—in a sense, "flattening" the output slightly.

```
d = {
    'G': {'G': 
            {'T': 
                {'A': 'end'},
             'C': 'end'}
         }, 
    'C': {'G': 'end'}
}

# Transform a dictionary to a list using the given transformation function.
# The transformation function must take a key and value and return a sequence,
# which will be spliced into the output list. No ordering is imposed on the
# keys of the dictionary.
def transform(d, f):
    out = []
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        out.extend(f(k, v))
    return out

def nested_dict_to_list(key, value):
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        # don't recurse into this value
        return [key]
    else:
        return [key, transform(value, nested_dict_to_list)]


>>> transform(d, nested_dict_to_list)
['C', ['G'], 'G', ['G', ['C', 'T', ['A']]]]
```

*Edited:* The problem previously used `{'$': '$'}` as the sentinel value, but now simply uses `'end'`; updating the code accordingly.

Comment: What happened to the sub dict `{'$': '$'}` under `'A'` and `'C'`?

Comment: +1, but the result is a little differs from question just as mine

Comment: @dawg It was rejected, as I think it should have been. I interpreted the question's desired results as implying that {'$', '$'} was a sentinel value to indicate where to stop recursing—though it doesn't appear to be strictly necessary in this example.

Comment: @npdu Yup, I see it now.